# Курс: МКА Python(Junior) Тема: Создание игры «камень, ножницы, бумага»

Tags: python, строки, подстрока

Задание
Реализуйте программу, цель которой определить, есть ли в тексте определённое слово.
Пользователь вставляет в консоль текст, а потом слово, которое хочет найти, программа
должна вывести номер позиции, в которой
начинается это слово и есть ли оно вообще.
Учтите регистр букв (маленькие и большие),
чтобы программа находила любой из вариантов.

---

Код:

```
import random 
a = input("Введите строку: ") 
s = input("Введите слово: ") 
n = a.lower().find(s.lower()) 
if n < 0: 
    print("Слово не содержится в строке") 
while n >= 0: 
    print("Слово содержится в строке в позиции", n)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вы даже не пытались сделать что-то сами. Вы хотите, чтобы домашку сделали за вас.

Comment: import random
a = input("Введите строку: ")
s = input("Введите слово: ")

n = a.lower().find(s.lower())

if n < 0:
    print("Слово не содержится в строке")

while n >= 0:
    print("Слово содержится в строке в позиции", n)
    я хз

Comment: А что собственно с этим кодом не так?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проверяем наличие подстроки методом `.find()`:

```
t=input('Введите строку --> ').lower()
s=input('Введите слово --> ').lower()
if (pos:=t.find(s)) == -1:
    print('Такой подстроки нет')
else:
    print(f'Подстрока есть, её позиция {pos}')
```

Для тех, кто любит коды, запиханные в строчку =):

```
print('Такой подстроки нет' if (pos:=input('Введите строку --> ').lower().find(input('Введите слово --> ').lower())) == -1 else f'Подстрока есть, её позиция {pos}')
```

Для тех, у кого питон ниже `3.8` и не поддерживает оператор `:=`:

```
t=input('Введите строку --> ').lower()
s=input('Введите слово --> ').lower()
pos=t.find(s)
if pos == -1:
    print('Такой подстроки нет')
else:
    print(f'Подстрока есть, её позиция {pos}')
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы используете `while` вместо `if`, и у вас образуется бесконечный цикл.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: Если помог, поставьте галочку:)

Comment: @pytyrre чем не устраивает ответ?

Comment: За что убрали галочку и поставили минус?

Comment: Изменил, добавил перевод в нижний регистр

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка, на такие вопросы (учебные задания) лучше не надо отвечать. (минус ставил не я)

Comment: @wchistow как думаете, удалить?)

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка, вы уже помогли автору решить его домашку, теперь уже нет смысла удалять. Просто больше так не делайте )

Comment: Ладно))) Не буду

Comment: Не понял ток, почему галочку убрал